# Call non-static method (located in main class) from different class

Tags: java, android

**Thank you all for your answers and time!**

Hello,

I've been trying to call a non-static method, located in my main application Class, from the Preferences Class.
Because the method I call is not static, I instantiate the main class and then try to call the specific method I want but it's force closing.

**Preferences.class (from where I call the method):**

```
Preference sorted = (Preference) findPreference("sortPref");
        sorted.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                Object d = new mainActivity();
                ((mainActivity) d).queryBookmarks();

                return true;
            }
        });
```

**the mainActivity.class method I call:**

```
    public void queryBookmarks() {

        Toast.makeText(context, "blah blah", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
//context is not null and the Toast is working if I  call it from mainActivity.class

        }
```

**The Logcat:**

```
E/AndroidRuntime(11718): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(11718): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(11718):        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getContentReso
lver(ContextWrapper.java:90)
E/AndroidRuntime(11718):        at android.app.Activity.managedQuery(Activity.ja
va:1520)
E/AndroidRuntime(11718):        at com.queryBookmarks(
.java:101)
E/AndroidRuntime(11718):        at com.Preferences$2.onPrefer
enceChange(Preferences.java:47)
E/AndroidRuntime(11718):        at android.preference.Preference.callChangeListe
ner(Preference.java:756)
E/AndroidRuntime(11718):        at android.preference.ListPreference.onDialogClo
sed(ListPreference.java:219)
E/AndroidRuntime(11718):        at android.preference.DialogPreference.onDismiss
(DialogPreference.java:384)
E/AndroidRuntime(11718):        at android.app.Dialog$ListenersHandler.handleMes
sage(Dialog.java:1047)
E/AndroidRuntime(11718):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.ja
va:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(11718):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(11718):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThrea
d.java:4627)
E/AndroidRuntime(11718):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native
Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(11718):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:5
21)
E/AndroidRuntime(11718):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndA
rgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
E/AndroidRuntime(11718):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(Zygot
eInit.java:626)
E/AndroidRuntime(11718):        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

D/dalvikvm(11718): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 4248 objects / 282248 bytes in 40ms
W/ActivityManager(  244):   Force finishing activity com.package/.Pre
ferences
```

Appreciate any help! :)

EDIT: I can't make queryBookmarks() a static function because it uses Android function managedQuery which is not a static function.

Comment: No doubt about it... I'm a beginner in both Android and Java and I'm learning the basics while developing something for practice purposes.

Comment: @Falmarri Obviously he is trying to learn Java, it would be more helpful if you would point out specific problems with his code, or explain why his approach is wrong.

Comment: It's hard to point out specific problems with code when you just post a very small part, and clearly have very big holes in fundamental knowledge of java and OO programming

Comment: If `Dmarks` is an `Activity` class, you should never, every instantiate it with `new`. If you need to communicate between 2 activities, use intents or communicate through a service.

Comment: Thanks for replying.
Yeah, Dmarks is an Activity (ListActivity). I'll read about the use of intents in order to communicate between 2 activities (hopefully I understand Android API and Java better in time).
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dmarks is your primary `Application` class?  You should not try to instantiate this in your `Activity`.  Instead, use the [getApplication](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getApplication%28%29) function in your Activity to get the current instance.

You will need to cast it to your subclass type:

```
DMark dmark = (DMark)getApplication();
dmark.queryBookmarks();
```

Comment: Mayra,
Thanks for replying!

Dmarks is my primary Application class.

If I understood right, I should put this:
Dmarks dmark = (Dmarks)getApplication();
dmark.queryBookmarks();

instead of the:
Dmarks d = new Dmarks();
d.queryBookmarks();

I tried this and got "Cannot cast from Application to Dmarks".

Comment: By primary application class, I mean a class that extends "Application".  From your error, it sounds like that is not the case.

Comment: oh.. no. Dmarks extends the main activity class (listActivity). Thanks for trying to help! :)

Comment: Oh, ok.  There is no way to call a member function from one activity in another activity.  You need to rethink your class organization.  What is this function trying to do?  Why do you need it in both Activities?  You could create a common base class for your Activities, or move it into an Application subclass.

Comment: Basically I want to run a sorting function when user selects the orderBy (title ASC, title DESC, most visited) from the Preferences Activity. I've managed to perform action when user selects one of the above but I want to actually perform the sort before he exist the Preferences Activity back to the Main Activity (using the "Back" device button).
The sorting function is located inside the Main Activity Class. Perhaps I should consider, as you suggested, to move it outside to a shared Class (sort of a Helper Class). Will I be able to call if from the Preference Class that way?

Comment: It sounds like you have a data model that you want shared between multiple activities?  I would place that in an Application subclass, where it can be accessed from all Activities.  The Activity class itself should only be responsible for the view.  In the model-view-control pattern, your Activity is the view while the Application contains the model and is the controller.

Comment: Many thanks for all your help! You definitely opened my mind and pointed me to the right direction in order to find the solution ;)
Greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Make `Dmarks` implement `Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener` instead. Then you'll have a properly initialized context.

Comment: I tried putting this code inside the Main Activity Class but It can't recognize findPreference().
----
Preference sorted = (Preference) findPreference("sortPref");
  sorted.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
   public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
    
    //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Bookmarks sorted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return true;
   }
  });

Comment: Change your class declaration to `class Dmarks implements Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener` and then add the `onPreferenceChange()` method to your class.

Comment: Dmarks -> public class Dmarks extends ListActivity.
So I had to do: public class Dmarks extends ListActivity implements OnPreferenceChangeListener. no error but nothing happens. I'll look into it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Where does `context` come from? It sounds like the exception is that `context` is null. Do you need to inject the `context` into your `Dmarks` instance yourself? Somehow, this value needs to be set.

Also, what is the point of code like this

```
Object d = new Dmarks();
((Dmarks) d).queryBookmarks();
```

instead of just writing

```
Dmarks d = new Dmarks();
d.queryBookmarks();
```

?

Comment: as I mentioned in the comment, context is not null and the queryBookmarks() method works perfectly when I call it from within Dmarks.class.

regarding the code writing, you're right... no point :) just pure Eclipse auto-completion.

Comment: by the way, this is not the real queryBookmarks() method. It's much longer... but as I said, it's been tested and worked perfect so it's no what causing the force close. (also tested getBaseContext() instead of context... works as well)

Comment: Well there's a difference between how queryBookmarks() runs in a normal Dmarks instance and how it runs when you simply create a new instance with the no-arg constructor. Perhaps the Android runtime is injecting some of the classes dependencies? What happens at `ContextWrapper.java:90`? That's the real source of the NPE.

Comment: I think you are right and it's a problem with the context but I've tried replacing context with everything - getBaseContext(), getApplicationContext() and even Dmarks.this - same force close... I have no idea what am I missing :\

Answer (score 0):

Contex maybe not null but looks like it's missing something, why don't you try to inject the actual instance of main class into Prefernces?

```
//in main    
preferncesInstance.setDmarks(this);
```

Then you can call queryBook on working instance...

Comment: not sure if I understood right on where to put this but I get "Syntax error on token "this", delete this token"

Answer (score 0):

i Think you must also call toast setView() and send suitable view